# Google Calendar Remove Start Date for Multi Day Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have script that removes the end day for multi-day events. I want to be able to do the same to remove the start day for multi-day events. Can anyone help?

```
let excludeEnddate = e.isAllDayEvent() //exclude end date if it's an all day event
function getDaysArray(start, end, excludeEnddate) {
  if (excludeEnddate) {
    for (var arr = [], dt = new Date(start); dt < new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
      arr.push(formatDate(dt));
    }
  }
  else {
    for (var arr = [], dt = new Date(start); dt <= new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
      arr.push(formatDate(dt));
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. I think the reason I was getting unusual results was having the Google Calendar time zone set to something other than +0.